# Usar Form relativo em UserControl

Tags: c#, winforms

Estou tentando criar um UserControl para que possa chamar diferentes Forms, entretanto alterando apenas nos controles ele faça a chamada.

Apresenta o erro que o Form "Formulario" é inexistente.

```
  public partial class campos_busca : UserControl
    {
        public Form Formulario
        {
            get; set;
        }
        public campos_busca()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Campos_busca_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void TextBox1_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            Formulario f = new Formulario();
        }
```

Comment: O campo "Formulario" é variavel, ex:
Defini "Form Formulario = Frm_produtos"

Quando o evento doubleclick acionar seria como:
Frm_produtos f = new Frm_Produtos();
f.ShowDialog();

Quando definir "Form Formulario = Frm_Funcionarios":
Frm_Funcionarios f = new Frm_Funcionarios();
f.ShowDialog();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você está tentando instanciar uma classe que não existe, logo, o compilador irá indicar que ela não existe (obviamente). Ao tentar invocar o `new Formulario`, ele irá procurar pela classe `Formulario`, que por ora, não existe.

Se estiver tentando instanciar o `Form` que está em `Formulario`, atribua uma instância ao valor da propriedade. <sub>(Exemplo disso no final)</sub>

---

Se você quer que seu `UserForm` chame outro `Form`, remova o `new` ao tentar instanciar um objeto instanciado.

```
 public partial class campos_busca : UserControl
    {
        public Form Formulario
        {
            get; set;
        }
        public campos_busca()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Campos_busca_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void TextBox1_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            // Formulario f = new Formulario();  < ~~ você está tentando instanciar a propriedade Formulario
            Formulario.ShowDialog();  // < ~~ está a chamar o ShowDialog de sua propriedade Formulario
        }
    }
```

E para especificar que irá chamar um determinado formulário, associe ele na sua propriedade:

```
campos_busca cbusca = new campos_busca();
cbusca.Formulario = new Frm_produtos();
```

Ao chamar o evento `MouseDoubleClick` dentro do `cbusca`, irá chamar o `ShowDialog` de `Frm_produtos` instanciado.

Answer (score 1):

É um pouco complexo responder a pergunta sem entender todo o contexto. Porém o que eu sugiro é que a parte de criação do formulário fique por conta de quem utilizar o `UserControl`.

Algo do tipo:

```
var meuCampo = new campos_busca(); //--- Você pode omitir isso aqui
meuCampo.Formulario = new FrmFuncionarios(); //---- Essa parte você coloca na criação do formulário que contém o seu UserControl, por exemplo.
```

Dentro do seu `UserControl` você pode trabalhar com o Form normalmente. Mas lembre-se de verificar se ele já foi criado.

No meu caso eu trabalho com herança de formulário e implemento os métodos de criação desses formulários como métodos virtuais que sempre devem ser implementados na herança. Como eu te disse, o contexto pode ser outro.

Espero ter ajudado